# Matching only first occurence of whitespace using regex

Tags: regex

I have a .txt file and I'm trying to match the first whitespace in the line (so I can replace it with a tab). I'd like to do carry out the match on each line.

An example of the type of text is:

```
2014-05-09 12:28:06 Lab bench another
2014-06-10 01:28:31 Membrane test initiated 
2014-05-11 12:38:04 Membrane test initiated 
2014-05-13 14:38:06 Membrane test initiated 
2014-05-13 12:38:17 Membrane capacitance 
2014-05-14 16:38:17 Membrane resistance
```

If I use `(?<!n.*)n` I can match the first 'n' in each line but if I use `(?<!\s.*)\s` to match the first whitespace, I only match the first whitespace of the whole text (not on each line).

I'm using EditPad Pro and its multiline search function.

Comment: You can search for: `^\S*\s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(\S+)\s+
```

Try this.Replace by `$1\t` or `\1\t`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/35